# Maven project not available in netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I'm trying to use `flying saucer`, and to do that I have to build it though their `pom.xml`. I'm also currently using NetBeans, and from my understanding it is supposed to be shipped with their later builds (later meaning 6.5+), however there is no such option for me to use maven when creating a project.

These are the options available for me atm;
[image: Available project options]

Also, I checked the plugins, and there is no maven plugin there, do I have to install the plugin manually?

Thanks for any responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I had installed NetBeans from the software manager, which did not include Maven, even though it was version 8.1.

This was fixed by getting the NetBeans 8.2 version from oracle, that included the maven plug-in by default.

It seems rather misleading that according to NetBeans, maven is shipped with the default installation of NetBeans IDE, yet somehow it wasn't included.

[NetBeans on maven](http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenBestPractices)

Answer (score 1):

you are likely missing a few plugins. Check Tools/Plugins main menu dialog and install the maven related plugins.

Answer (score -1):

You can add maven support considering you can't update you can just download and use maven directly in the command line and build from the pom.xml

```
cd to dir..

mvn install
```

and it will do it's thing.

Download is here https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Comment: I have maven installed since earlier, however I want to open up the project in NetBeans as a maven project, and a `pom.xml`.